# Передача данных между потоками Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Помогите с потоками разобраться.

Делаю приложение с 2 потоками:

- 1й поток получает данные каким-либо образом
- 2й поток их отображает если данные получены

Если использовать глобальную переменную, то как отследить в целевом потоке, что данные получены?

```
import threading

def setwindow():
    print("здесь должны быть данные из другого потока") 

def read_data(): 
  i = 0
  while (i != -1):
    i = int (input("Введите i: "))
    #дальше в целевой поток передать надо

#Делаем потоки
t1 = threading.Thread(target=setwindow)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=read_data)
#запускаем
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Спасибо всем неравнодушным

Comment: Если приложение у вас было бы на `Qt` предложил бы использовать `QThread` с сигналами для передачи данных между потоками :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать очереди:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

```
q = Queue()
...
    q.put(item)
...
    item = q.get()
```

Можно блокироваться на `get` с таймаутом.

Comment: СПАСИБО за ответ!